# Firebase Simple Login - new emails not registering to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

im trying to implement firebase's simple login (email/password). the code i have works when hard coded but i cannot get it to pick up the inputs and log to firebase. its not giving me any errors, its simply not creating the user in my firebase. any tips?

my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Ygs3E/2/

```
var myRootRef = new Firebase('https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/');
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(myRootRef, function (user) {
});

$("#registerUser").on("click", function() {
auth.createUser("email", "password", function () {})
})

<form>
Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br>
<input id="registerUser" type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: You can view the created users by visiting your account dashboard and going to Simple Login -> Email/Password. There will be a list of simple login creds. But as David said, you need to store your own profiles in order to read them from Firebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Simple Login is just an authentication server, it doesn't store any information into your Firebase. You can easily do that inside of your `createUser` function however.

```
var email = // get email textbox value
var pass = // get password textbox value
$("#registerUser").on("click", function() {
    auth.createUser(email, pass, function (error, user) {
       // if there's no error save the user to the users location
       // and use the uid as the key to store the user
       if(!error) {
          myRootRef.child("users").child(user.uid).set(user);
       }
    });
});
```

In regards to Kato's comment. This is will only create a user not log one in.

Comment: Depending on security rules, may also want to log in first.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I started using `Password` authentication service of Firebase.  In addition to all the previous answers regarding account creation and storage of user information, make sure that you `Enable Email & Password Authentication`

- Go to the Account Dashboard.
- Select your Firebase.
- Choose the Login & Auth tab.
- Select the tab for Email & Password
- Make sure `Enable Email & Password Authentication` option is checked

For additional information, please checkout [Firebase User Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html) page.